# How can I include a specific library into Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

My robot framework installation did not include [DateTime](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/DateTime.html?r=2.8.5) library. But i want to use it now. How can i do it with current installation intact ?

```
>pybot --version
Robot Framework 2.8.4 (Python 2.7.7 on win32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to upgrade to robot framework 2.8.5 or greater. I don't think there's any reason to be concerned about an upgrade from 2.8.4 to 2.8.5.

Your other choice is to opy the DateTime library into somewhere in your PATH. You can get the latest version of the library here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/DateTime.py

Answer (score 0):

DateTime Library is included in Robot Framework by default.
I would be very surprised if you date have it.
To make sure, you don't have it, run a simple test like this:

```
*** Settings ***
library  DateTime

*** test cases ***
date_test
    ${date} =  Get Current Date
    log to console  ${date}
```

You should get something along those lines:

```
[MBP]$ pybot date.robot
==============================================================================
Date
==============================================================================
date_test                                                             .
2014-11-19 08:47:01.736
date_test                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

If you don't, then please share what you get.

Comment: C:\Users\Narendra Petkar>pybot samplerobo.robot
==============================================================================
Samplerobo
==============================================================================
date_test                                                             | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Get Current Date' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samplerobo                                                            | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed

Comment: did you put the "library  DateTime" statement? in the Settings section? Please share your whole test source code.

Comment: the OP states they are using 2.8.4; DateTime started shipping with 2.8.5.

Comment: ah ok sorry, thought this lib was there for a while somehow. Thanks.